# How to download multiple files with Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
async function download(stuff) {
    if (stuff.length > 1) {
        //What do I do?
    } else if (stuff.length === 1) {
        const link= stuff[0];
        axios({
            url: `/link`,
            method: "GET",
            responseType: "blob", // important
        }).then((response) => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "myFile.jpg"
            a.click();
        });
    }
}
```

I use this and it works fine when I want to download a single file. But if `stuff` contains more elements, I would like to download them all. One after another doesn't work well, as the user has to confirm them separately. So, I would like to download them all together as a zip file. Is there a recommended method how to do that?

Comment: [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

Comment: Hi, did you find a reasonable solution to your problem?